# Sending multiple emails through Gmail smtp using javax mail class triggers connection refused error occasionally

Tags: android, gmail, jakarta-mail

I'm sending multiple emails with attachments through Gmail SMTP using javax mail class.
The email sending is done inside AsyncTask in the doInBackground() function. I have an arraylist of mails and I'm sending them one by one. The first email sends successfully, but from the next email I get the MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host. 
I am not so sure why this problem occurs. Is it possible that the required resource is not released? Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

> 04-30 10:10:25.109: W/System.err(619): javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
>   04-30 10:10:25.109: W/System.err(619):   nested exception is:
>   04-30 10:10:25.109: W/System.err(619):  java.net.ConnectException: localhost/127.0.0.1:25 - Connection refused
>   04-30 10:10:25.109: W/System.err(619):  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1391)
>   04-30 10:10:25.109: W/System.err(619):  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
>   04-30 10:10:25.109: W/System.err(619):  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
>   04-30 10:10:25.109: W/System.err(619):  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
>   04-30 10:10:25.109: W/System.err(619):  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
>   04-30 10:10:25.109: W/System.err(619):  at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
>   04-30 10:10:25.109: W/System.err(619):  at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
>   04-30 10:10:25.109: W/System.err(619):  at com.waratah.app.Mail.send(Mail.java:123)
>   04-30 10:10:25.109: W/System.err(619):  at com.waratah.app.ScheduledService$SendEmailAsyncTask.doInBackground(ScheduledService.java:1368)
>   04-30 10:10:25.109: W/System.err(619):  at com.waratah.app.ScheduledService$SendEmailAsyncTask.doInBackground(ScheduledService.java:1)
>   04-30 10:10:25.109: W/System.err(619):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
>   04-30 10:10:25.109: W/System.err(619):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
>   04-30 10:10:25.109: W/System.err(619):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>   04-30 10:10:25.109: W/System.err(619):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
>   04-30 10:10:25.109: W/System.err(619):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
>   04-30 10:10:25.109: W/System.err(619):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
>   04-30 10:10:25.109: W/System.err(619): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: localhost/127.0.0.1:25 - Connection refused
>   04-30 10:10:25.113: W/System.err(619):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:207)
>   04-30 10:10:25.113: W/System.err(619):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:437)
>   04-30 10:10:25.113: W/System.err(619):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:983)
>   04-30 10:10:25.113: W/System.err(619):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:926)
>   04-30 10:10:25.113: W/System.err(619):  at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
>   04-30 10:10:25.113: W/System.err(619):  at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
>   04-30 10:10:25.113: W/System.err(619):  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1359)
>   04-30 10:10:25.113: W/System.err(619):  ... 15 more

My send email asynctask class

```
class SendEmailAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Boolean> {
    Mail thisMail;

    public SendEmailAsyncTask() {
        if(V) Log.v(SendEmailAsyncTask.class.getName(), "SendEmailAsyncTask()");
        this.thisMail = mailQueue.get(mailCounter);
        sendMessageToClient("Sending " + thisMail.getRecipients());

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if(V) Log.v(SendEmailAsyncTask.class.getName(), "doInBackground()");
        try {
            thisMail.send();
            return true;
        } catch (AuthenticationFailedException e) {
            Log.e(SendEmailAsyncTask.class.getName(), "Gmail account details are wrong");
            createNotification("Gmail account details are incorrect. Please check them in the settings.");
            setFlag(FLAG_BAD_ACCOUNT);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            Log.e(SendEmailAsyncTask.class.getName(), thisMail.getRecipients() + " sending failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(result) { // email send success
            //sent successfully 
            if(D) Log.d(SendEmailAsyncTask.class.getName(), "email sent successfully");
            sendMessageToClient("Email sent");
        } else {
            //retry? or quit
            if(D) Log.d(SendEmailAsyncTask.class.getName(), "email was not sent");
            sendMessageToClient("Email not sent");
        }       

            mailCounter++;
            // if there are more mails in the queue start another send email task
            if (mailCounter < mailQueue.size()) {
                SendEmailAsyncTask sendTask = new SendEmailAsyncTask();
                sendTask.execute();

            // if there are no more in the mail queue, delete the data set
            } else {
                deleteTask = new DeleteFilesAsyncTask(currentDataSet.getDate(), currentDataSet.getMachine());
                deleteTask.execute();
            }

        sendTask = null;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Looking through my Mail wrapper class the port I'm using is 465, not 25. I'm wondering if that means something?

```
public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {   
private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
private String user;   
private String password;   
private Session session;   
private Multipart multipart;
private String subject;
private String body;
private String sender;
private String recipients;

static {   
    Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());   
}  

public Mail(String user, String password) {
    this.user = user;   
    this.password = password;   
    multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    Properties props = new Properties();   
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

    //session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    session = Session.getInstance(props, this);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay since no one seems to have an answer... I'll answer my own question.

I got around the problem by sending the emails as soon as I create them instead of scheduling the sending later.

Previous code: 
(Had error after one successful send)

```
class CreateEmailAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // create emails and add to the queue
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        SendEmailAsyncTask sendTask = new SendEmailAsyncTask();
        sendTask.execute();
}

class SendEmailAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // send emails
    }
}
```

Changed code:
(Works well for all emails)

```
class CreateEmailAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // create emails
        // send emails
    }
}
```

I think there might be a time-out or something that makes the mail objects invalid, but I'm not sure. I checked the [Java Mail API documentation](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/) but couldn't find much information...